# Why slash command doesnt appear with Cog?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have this code in my cog:

```
class Admin(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot: discord.Bot):
    self.bot = bot

@slash_command(name="create-embed", description="Test")
async def create_embed(self, ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    block.has_role(ctx, env.METACORE_MODERATOR_ROLE_ID)

    embed_title = 'Test title'
    view = v.CreateEmbedView()
    view.bot = self.bot
    view.author_id = ctx.author.id
    result_embed = discord.Embed(title=embed_title)
    embed_message = await ctx.respond(embed=result_embed, view=view, ephemeral=True)
    view.embed = result_embed
    view.embed_message = embed_message

 
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Admin(bot))
```

But the slash command create-embed doesn't appears. And in my main.py I have:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    admin.setup(bot)
```

Comment: no errors in console (logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing from the `admin.setup` that you're importing the cog file.

First off is that application commands (slash commands) are registered before `on_ready` is called in pycord. So if you want to add cogs like this, you'd need to do it as such:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    admin.setup()
    await bot.sync_commands()
```

***HOWEVER***, cogs aren't supposed to be added like this. Instead, you should not import the cog file and use `load_extension` to load your cog. Example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    bot.load_extension("admin")
    await bot.sync_commands()
```

This way is cleaner and allows you to reload your cogs at runtime. Also a better place to ask questions like this is through the [support server](https://discord.gg/pycord).